# Virtual Machine Manager can't launch create dialog — pci.ids is missing

Tags: virtual-machine, pci, virt-manager

I'm using Pop!_OS 20.10, and I've installed `virt-manager` using `apt`. However, whenever I click "Create new virtual machine" in the application, the following error pops up:

```
Error launching create dialog: g-io-error-quark: Error opening file /usr/share/misc/pci.ids: No such file or directory (1)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/createvm.py", line 111, in show_instance
    cls._instance = vmmCreateVM()
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/createvm.py", line 188, in __init__
    self._init_state()
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/createvm.py", line 324, in _init_state
    self._os_list = vmmOSList()
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/oslist.py", line 39, in __init__
    self._init_state()
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/oslist.py", line 55, in _init_state
    all_os = virtinst.OSDB.list_os()
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/osdict.py", line 274, in list_os
    for name, osobj in self._all_variants.items():
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/osdict.py", line 198, in _all_variants
    loader = self._os_loader
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/osdict.py", line 190, in _os_loader
    loader.process_default_path()
gi.repository.GLib.GError: g-io-error-quark: Error opening file /usr/share/misc/pci.ids: No such file or directory (1)
```

I've looked up “pci.ids”, and it seems like it's a system file, so why is it not there? `lspci` works fine.

The version of `virt-manager` is 2.2.1, from the official Pop!_OS/Ubuntu (unsure) repos.

Since it has been requesten, the output of `apt list | grep libosinfo`:

```
gir1.2-libosinfo-1.0/groovy,now 1.7.1-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libosinfo-1.0-0/groovy,now 1.7.1-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libosinfo-1.0-dev/groovy 1.7.1-1 amd64
libosinfo-bin/groovy 1.7.1-1 amd64
libosinfo-l10n/groovy,groovy 1.7.1-1 all
```

An additional note: In the folder mentioned in the error, there is a file with a similar name, but gzipped. Output of `ls -lARF` in `/usr/share/misc`:

```
.:
total 940
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  44283 Feb 24  2018 config.guess*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  36136 Feb 24  2018 config.sub*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     13 May 16  2020 magic -> ../file/magic/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     24 May 16  2020 magic.mgc -> ../../lib/file/magic.mgc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 288895 Apr  1 16:46 pci.ids.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 292413 Apr  1 16:46 pci.ids.gz.new
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 292413 Apr  1 16:46 pci.ids.gz.neww
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      0 Jan 30 12:52 pci.ids.gz.old
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     25 Aug 26  2020 usb.ids -> /var/lib/usbutils/usb.ids
```

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue, I know it's "hacky", but could you please detail what you did to solve the issue? What did you unzip?

Comment: I unzipped `/usr/share/misc/pci.ids.gz`.

Comment: Strange but that alone does appear to fix it, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

I have exactly same versions of `libosinfo` and `virt-manager`, but I'm running `focal` distro (yours is `groovy`).
Just as you can see, the file `pci.ids` is not present at `/usr/share/misc`. Try purging and reinstalling `virt-manager`. If that doesn't help, it is a bug (`libosinfo/groovy`) and should be reported.

For comparison, here are my outputs of whatever I've requested from you.

```
$ apt list | grep libosinfo

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

gir1.2-libosinfo-1.0/focal,now 1.7.1-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libosinfo-1.0-0/focal,now 1.7.1-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libosinfo-1.0-dev/focal 1.7.1-1 amd64
libosinfo-bin/focal 1.7.1-1 amd64
libosinfo-l10n/focal,focal 1.7.1-1 all

$ tree /usr/share/misc
/usr/share/misc
├── magic -> ../file/magic
├── magic.mgc -> ../../lib/file/magic.mgc
├── pci.ids
└── usb.ids -> /var/lib/usbutils/usb.ids

1 directory, 3 files
```

**/EDIT**

`virt-manager` should've installed `libosinfo` packages along with it.

Can you please post the output of `apt list | grep libosinfo` and `tree /usr/share/misc`?

Comment: I have added the output of that command to the question.

Comment: Forgot to mention to reinstall `libosinfo` as well, it's the one responsible for these files. Sorry.

Comment: Nope, reinstalling both of the matching packages (with `sudo apt reinstall gir1.2-libosinfo-1.0 libosinfo-1.0-0`) didn't fix it. There is still no file.

Comment: I've made it work by unzipping the file, but it feels hacky

Comment: @schuelermine glad it worked, but you're 100% right